# How to test push notification on the Apple watch?

Tags: apple-watch

I'm able to test push notification using Apple Watch simulator and the "PushNotificationPayload.apns" file by selecting Notification:

[image]

**How to test push notification on the actual Apple Watch?**
--> I've tried to use exact steps for simulator. But the Apple Watch will just launch the app, bypassing the notification view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APNS file is available only for testing in the simulator. It doesn't work on a real device. You'll have to test push notifications the same way you would for an iOS app: actually sending a push notification to the device.

Comment: can you please help out with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252953/how-to-set-apple-watch-code-signing-identity-and-provisioning-profile-for-push-n

Comment: I tried to send push notification , it delivered to iPhone device not iWatch .

Comment: @NadaGamal By default it will only go to the Watch if your phone is locked and you are wearing the Watch. If you have an issue beyond that, I'd suggest starting a new question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple process to test the push notification on Apple Watch. It is same as in iPhone. Also Inside your iPhone -> Apple Watch-> Notifications -> Mirror iPHONE alerts From-> turn on your notification.

There are following things which you need to take care while testing the Push notification on Watch:-

1) IPhone should not be active and Watch should be active.

2) IPhone and watch both should not be active.

3) IPhone and watch both should not be deactive.

Comment: Thank you! It is the very problem I met!